# CSS class in iteration overwriten in react

Tags: css, reactjs, microsoft-edge

i'm currently working on rendering a set of elemens using map as follow:

```
 <div className="wrapperScoring">
              {TOPUPSCORER.map((item, i) => (
                <div key={i + 1} className="flexi">
                  <ShowScore/>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
```

the class "flexi" should be use to control how Showscore is render since the width is control by a div class automatically add.

[screenshoot of  Dev tool.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsMoe.png)

The flexi class is removed automatically, therefore the css style isn't applied. I would like the flexi class to use the whole properties of the wrapperScoring class.

do someone know why?

thanks

Comment: That looks like invalid syntax to me. Where's your closing div? Where's your closing callback? Where's your closing curly brace? What are those odd terminators??

Comment: I agree with Chris Happy's answer. First, please correct the syntax errors in your code and test again.

Comment: Could you please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**? I can't reproduce the issue with the code you provide. It has "flexi" class, you can check: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO9uo.png.

Answer (score 2):

As @code mentioned, your code appears invalid.

Try:

```
<div className="wrapperScoring">
   {TOPDOWNSCORER.map((item, i) => (
        <div key={i + 1} className="flexi">
          <ShowScore/>
        </div>
   ))}
</div>
```

Comment: the closing syntax was added, put just not posted here. i wanted the focus on the div with classname flexi. you can immagine that without the correct syntax, i would not be able to debug it in edge.